# How to solve problem with CSV Mapping using CsvHelper

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I have a CSV File with multiple fields(check below for format)

```
ArticleNumber;Shop1;Shop2;Shop3;Shop4;Shop5;Shop6;Shop7
123455;50;51;52;53;54;55;56
```

In fields Shop1,Shop2....Shop7 I have product Prices. I receive file like this, so I need to find a cool way to solve my problem.
I want to read this CSV using CsvHelper library, but I don't know how to map fields. As a result I want something like this:

| ArticleNumber | Shop | Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123455 | Shop1 | 50 |
| 123455 | Shop2 | 51 |
| 123455 | Shop3 | 52 |
| 123455 | Shop4 | 53 |
| 123455 | Shop5 | 54 |
| 123455 | Shop6 | 55 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will get you the format you are looking for.

```cs
void Main()
{
    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = ";"
    };
    
    using (var reader = new StringReader("ArticleNumber;Shop1;Shop2;Shop3;Shop4;Shop5;Shop6;Shop7\n123455;50;51;52;53;54;55;56\n123456;60;61;62;63;64;65;66"))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<ArticleMap>();
        
        csv.Read();
        csv.ReadHeader();
        
        var shops = csv.HeaderRecord.Skip(1).ToArray();
        
        var records = csv.GetRecords<Article>().ToList();

        var results = records.SelectMany(r => r.Shop
                                .Select((s, i) => new ArticleShop 
                                                    { 
                                                        ArticleNumber = r.ArticleNumber, 
                                                        Shop = shops[i], 
                                                        Price = s
                                                    })
                                ).ToList();
    }   
}

public class ArticleMap : ClassMap<Article>
{
    public ArticleMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.ArticleNumber);
        Map(x => x.Shop).Index(1);
    }
}

public class Article
{
    public int ArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public List<double> Shop { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleShop
{
    public int ArticleNumber { get; set; }
    public string Shop { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: David Specht, that worked like a charm. Thank you so much for your help. I apprechiate it.

Comment: Glad it works for you!  If this solves your question, it will be helpful for others if you mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Is the format of your CSV File set, or can it be changed?
If it can be changed you could change it to

```
ArticleNumber;Shop;Price
123455;Shop1;50
123455;Shop2;51
```

and so on

Edit: As I said in my comment you could also do it like this (this is Pseudo code only, I dont have c# open)

```
class PriceForArticle{
    int articleNumber;
    string shopName;
    float price;
}
```

and then you would have this Methode to initialise them into a list of PriceForArticle

```cs
List<PriceForArticle> prices = new List<PriceForArticle>();

for(int j = 1; j < AllArticles.Length; j++){
    for(int i = 1; i < AllArticles[j].Length; i++){
        prices.Add(new PriceForArticle(AllArticles[j][0], AllArticles[0][i], AllArticles[j][i]));
    }
}
```

Comment: FIle format is set, that's why I cannot change it. This way should be very easy, but I cannot change the file format.

Comment: Do you know how many shops your going to have or is the shop count variable?

Comment: For now I have only 7, but in the future it will be more.

Comment: You could probably create a Class that holds ArticleNumber, the Shop (or name or id, whatever) and the price. And then with a for loop, loop through every articlenumber in the csv list, and for them loop through the shops initialise them as an Object of your class and then add those to a list

Comment: I am going to try, even though I have tried but unsucessfully.

Comment: Thank Pablu for you help, but this code didn't worked for me. I tried in different way, but not sucessfull. I am trying to solve this somehow. Thanks.